# Formula for the lie derivatie of a vielbein

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

I wish to know what is the formula for the lie derivative of a vielbein say $e^{a}_{\mu}$ along $X^{\mu}$. Is it the same as the lie derivative of a vector?